# What software library can I use to tokenize attached words?

Tags: java, nlp

I have a set of strings like below:

```
maninthemiddle
saltnpepper
redcarsonly
gatonegro
baguettebiencuite
...
```

I'd like to extract words from each strings. The output would look like:

```
man in the middle
salt n pepper
red cars only
gato negro
baguette bien cuite
...
```

Some requirements:

- Library written in Java or have an already made bridge available (JNI)
- Should support English, French, Spanish
- Available on Maven